# Parse jSON in jquery and get response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a piece of code using getJSON to grab the data. The response looks like this:

```
[["SSP II",3],["Limitations",2],["Disputes",2],["PSS",4],["Debit Card",5]]
```

I am trying to loop through the response and build a simple table.

```
$.each(json, function(key, value) {
        alert(key + ' ' + value);
    });
```

I tried the above code but it alerts 0 [object Object].

How can I get the values from this response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[object Object]` means that you try to parse an object directly to a string (your `alert()`).

But if you want to see the actual values like `{name="SSP II"}`  you need to parse the json to a string like this:

`alert(key+ ' ', JSON.stringify(value));`

if you want to access the values of each array you could do this:

```
alert(value['name']);//alerts the first string ("SSP II")
```

Comment: `yntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
 

alert(key+ ' ', JSON.parse(value));`

Comment: `value` is not JSON, so you can't parse it as JSON.

Comment: sry i meant JSON.stringify :P

Comment: Doesn't really explain how to access the values though.

Comment: the alert is blank :/

Comment: what does `console.log(json);` show you?

Comment: @SBB: I believe the actual data is different from what you posted. As suggested in the duplicate answer, do `console.log` data first and inspect its structure. Then identify which information you want to access and use loops and property access accordingly.

Comment: console.log(json)returns 
`[Object { name="SSP II", y=3, visible=true}, Object { name="Limitations", y=2, visible=true}, Object { name="Disputes", y=2, visible=true}, Object { name="PSS", y=4, visible=true}, Object { name="Debit Card", y=5, visible=true}]`

Comment: then you need `value['name']` and not `value[0]` for example

Comment: That seemed to work - `alert(value['y'] + ' ' + value['name']);` - Will `Y` always be used as the value?

Comment: if you have a variable amount of keys, you could also use another loop. But yes, `value['y']` will always return the value in `[{y=""}]`